# Django duplicate key value violates unique constraint error model form

Tags: django, postgresql, django-forms, modelform

I have a legacy DB on PostgreSQL with a simple **products** table with 2 columns (productid, productname) with 70 products. I am trying to start using Django as a frontend and I have the model as below and a model form. The save process is failing with the error below.

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "productidentifier"
DETAIL:  Key (productid)=(4) already exists.
```

Could anyone help correct the error. I have confirmed on the Postgres table that the index get sequence is set right, expected value should be 72. See below the model, form and view.

```
#models.py
class Products(models.Model):
    productid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    productname = models.TextField(verbose_name='Product Name')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
#Views.py
def new_product(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= forms.EditProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save()
            return redirect('views.full_product_list')   
    else:
        form = forms.EditProductForm()
        return render(request, 'edit_product.html', {'form': form})

#forms.py
class EditProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    productname = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = models.Products
        fields = ('productname')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is propably some issue with your auto field sequence. You can use `./manage.py sqlsequencereset` to fix that. It will generate SQL queries to fix sequence on your tables.